# Hibernate creates a lot of connections

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, database-connection

I use Hibernate + Spring Boot and DB is MySQL and after two days a have a lot of connection from 150 to 250. Here is my Bean that interacts with entities and DB. I think I handle all exceptions and close all connections

```
package com.root.lvrmmonitor.utils;

import com.root.lvrmmonitor.entities.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DBManager {

    public List<Item> getItemsList() {

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            return session.createQuery("from Item", Item.class).list();
        }
    }

    public DropTarget saveDropTarget(DropTarget dropTarget) {

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(dropTarget);
            tx.commit();
        }

        return dropTarget;
    }

    public void deleteDropTarget(DropTarget dropTarget) {
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(dropTarget);
            tx.commit();
        }
    }

    public void saveSuccess(Success success) {

        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(success);
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. I suggest you to ask a question. What problem are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code that shows how to handle transactions properly:

```java
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
try {
    session.save(dropTarget);
    tx.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx.isActive()) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

You can create a simple helper function like this:

```java
public static <T> T runInTransaction(Session session, Function<Session, T> task) {
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  try {
    T res = task(session);
    tx.commit();
    return res;
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (tx.isActive()) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
  }
}
```

and use it in your code like this:

```java
runInTransaction(session, s -> s.save(dropTarget));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling exceptions at all in the provided `DBManager` class.

Comment: Could you please give a code example for some method?

Comment: It's not much clear from  your question what are you doing and what do you mean by open connections. Do you mean stalled connections? You should provide some more details in your question.

Comment: I am about connections handling, I read that if I put openSession() method in try (), it will handle automatically

Comment: Yes that fine but sometime connections gets stalled because of exceptions and transactions failures not handled properly. Also there is a connection pool that keeps connection open even if you close session. So it depends on many factors.

Comment: Sorry for anxiety, but could you share gist with a good example

Comment: There can't be a straight forward example to explain as it depends on many factors. But let's see one case, if you are using PostgreSQL and if your code is as above, you may see many connections open with `idle in transact` state.